# Can I provide addresses instead of latitude and longitude to Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-maps-api-3

I'm building an application where users provide the addresses for their listings. It's certainly not practical to ask a simple user to provide the latitude and longitude for each address he provides!

Can I provide addresses to Google Maps API instead? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for retagging, but I think the `google-maps-api-v3` tag could be important here, to differentiate between the v2 API. The v2 API is still very popular.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It seemed like there were about five roughly-equivalent tags it and I guess I accidentally removed some information. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes of course. That can be done very easily, using the [Geocoding Services](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding) provided by the Google Maps JavaScript API. Consider the following example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
   <title>Google Maps Geocoding Demo 1</title> 
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" 
           type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head> 
<body> 
   <div id="map" style="width: 400px; height: 300px;"></div> 

   <script type="text/javascript"> 

   var address = 'London, UK';

   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
       mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
       zoom: 6
   });

   var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

   geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
   }, 
   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         new google.maps.Marker({
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            map: map
         });
         map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      }
   });

   </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Screenshot:

[image: Google Maps v3 Geocoding Demo]

You can simply substitute `'London, UK'` from the `address` variable to any location that supports geocoding in Google Maps.

Comment: How can this be refined, often I provide a street name in the address and it still drops a pin locating to the city.

Comment: The Geocoding API free plan quota allows only one request per day. This solution need payments (5 $ per 1000 requests): https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-and-billing?hl=en_US

Answer (score 0):

Could be refined if you provide the address with the format :
var address = '# Street, City';
var address = '127 Ledbury Rd, Notting Hill, London';